# Wordpress New Install - Err: The requested URL /blog/index.php was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress

Doing a new install of WordPress 3.4.2
When I tried to install the blog using `.../blog/wp-admin/install.php`

I got an error message:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /blog/index.php was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.2 Server at mysite.com Port 80

1. I deleted all the files in the folder and installed again, same message.
2. I tried to change file permissions of install.php and index.php to 755, still didn't work

Comment: did you look at the apache logs what files are tried to access?

Answer (score 0):

> > I tried to change file permissions of install.php and index.php to 755, still didn't work

Did you check the owner and group of the file ? A command of the type will help you change the permissions:
Root > chown -R user:user /path/to/files

It's recommended to take up an auto-installer to install a wide library of scripts.